# How can I query unique columns, conditionally choosing which row based on another column's value?

Tags: mysql

I have the following setup:

```
date | event | hits

Jan  |   A   |  0
Jan  |   B   |  2
Jan  |   C   |  0
Feb  |   A   |  4
Feb  |   B   |  0
Feb  |   C   |  0
```

And I'm looking for a query that returns:

- Events are unique (only return **[Jan | B | x]** or **[Feb | B | x]**, not both)
- Prioritize hits (so **[Jan | B | 2]** beats **[Feb | B | 0]**)
- Secondarily prioritize most recent date (**[Feb | C | 0]** beats **[Jan | C | 0]**)

I would want the query for the above table to return:

```
Feb | A | 4
Jan | B | 2
Feb | C | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
(select edate from stuff sx where s.event=sx.`Event`  ORDER BY sx.hits DESC,sx.edate DESC limit 1) date,
s.event, (select hits from stuff sx where s.event=sx.`Event`  ORDER BY sx.hits DESC,sx.edate  DESC limit 1) hits
 FROM stuff s
GROUP BY Event
order by event
```

Table stuff edate field is defined as date.
Not very efficient for large tables, but works.